# Pandas sends me a warning when using pd.reset_option('all')

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reset all my rows and columns to pandas' default DataFrame format (truncated)

```
pd.reset_option('all')
```

but I'm getting a warning:

```
C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\_config\config.py:630: FutureWarning:
: boolean
    use_inf_as_null had been deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead.
```

What command can I use instead? I tried to follow the recommendation "Use `use_inf_as_na`" but it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem like something that you need to change. I guess `pd.reset_option('all')` still calls `use_inf_as_null` under the hood but that's not something you need to worry. That's just a warning and they will probably update the code before it is completely deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `silent=True`, and there would be no warning:

```
pd.reset_option('all', silent=True)
```

IMO This is the best way.